# Android - get event of app background restoring - like appdelegate in iOS

Tags: android, ios

There is an excellent feature in ios - a method in appdelegate that is called by ios when the **whole** app returns to interaction with the user. On android there is an onResume() method on each activity controller which runs the same from outside as from inside of your application (depends on previous activity on the stack). So you can not understand from which side was the segue - from inner or outside. For example, you wish to lock the screen of your app each time it restores from background. If you have a huge number of activities and segues between them in your app - you'll have to pass a boolean flag each time to show the destination activity understands that it was called from inside the app (not from returning of another app) and the screen shouldn't be locked. Is there any better pattern for catching hiding\unhiding the whole app - like in ios?

Answer (score 0):

One approach would be to have a BaseActivity that all your activities inherit from and make it count the activities that are alive.
Example:

```
public class BaseActivity extends Activity {

    private static int sActivitiesAlive;

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        if (sActivitiesAlive == 0) {
            onFirstActivityResume();
        }
        sActivitiesAlive++;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        sActivitiesAlive--;
    }

    protected void onFirstActivityResume() {
        // Override in children activities
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Android doesn't have an equivalent method - the most similar callback is onResume() [(which gets called whenever your activity resumes)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html). If you want to track whether the user is active in a specific activity, you could manually store the Date whenever onPause() is called, then check whether X minutes have passed in onResume().

```
private static final long TIMEOUT = 60 * 1000; // 1 min
long lastInteraction; 

lastInteraction = new Date().getTime(); // set in onPause()
boolean isFromBackground = new Date().getTime() - lastInteraction > TIMEOUT; // check in onResume()
```